# Relation between Lipschitz and differentiablity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a Lipschitz function. Show that the set of all reals at which $f$ is differentiable in non-empty.

I know that if $f$ is differentiable and derivative is bounded then it is Lipschitz. I know that the converse is FALSE. For example $f(x)=|x|$.

But I've no idea how to prove this statement. Can anyone give some hint ?

Comment: A differentiable function need not to be Lipschitz. See $f(x)=x^2$ on the whole $\Bbb R$.

Comment: he said bounded derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set would be better than being merely non-empty.

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, then it differentiable almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ by [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher's_theorem).

Comment: Why would you want to go to Rademacher's theorem, which is really of interest only in higher dimensions, when the stanard Lebesgue theory in one variable handles the case at hand?

Comment: I agree with you that one does not need the full power of Rademacher's theorem, of which only the 1-D case is needed, which together with the Fubini-Tonelli theorem gives the higher dimension result. A better hint may have been "locally of bounded variation" than "Rademacher".

Answer (score 2):

Without Rademacher: $f$ Lipschitz implies $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ , and so it can be written as the difference of two increasing functions, hence $f$ is differentiable there, a.e.

Comment: Well it's not of BV on $\mathbb R.$ But it is BV on every closed bounded interval and that's enough. Actually  $f$ is absolutely continuous on every closed bounded interval, which by the standard Lebesgue theory, gives the existence of $f'(x)$ a.e.

Comment: Yes, I thought it went without saying. I will amend. Thanks.